# Set the lookup path of view folder of ejs in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have **app.js** in **Express_server** folder.Full location of aap.js is `I:\WEB Development\Node\Express_server\`

and I made **views** folder at the location `I:\WEB Development\Node\`

How can I set the lookup path of views folder to above location(I:\WEB Development\Node)?

code of my `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change your views default path:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'))
```

Comment: var path = require('path')

Answer (score 6):

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

require("./route/route.js")(app);

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'))
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```