# Failed to lookup view folder ejs in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am using Node.js framework Express with TypeScript. But when I set view engine and view folder it return error "Failed to lookup view \"notice\" in views directory \"/Users/hung/source/js/nodejs_example/views\"".
I do not know why the path to view folder has the "\" at the end. Here is my code

app.ts

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

controller.ts

```
async renderView(req: Request, res:Response, next:Function):Promise <void> {
    res.render('notice');
}
```

Project folder structure

- src

  - app.ts
  - views

    - notice.ejs
      ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the lookup path of view folder of ejs in express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903473/set-the-lookup-path-of-view-folder-of-ejs-in-express)

Comment: @PimentoWeb no I've tried but it still return the same error

Comment: The view notice doesn't seems to be in your folder, is it normal ? (the architecture you gave)... Else, try to append a '/' in order to to write `/views`...

Comment: @PimentoWeb sorry I've edited the question. The file notice.ejs is already in folder views

Comment: The path to the `views` folder doesn't have a forward slash at the end, that's escaping the quote character at the end of `\"/Users/hung/source/js/nodejs_example/views\"`.

Comment: @Graham oh thank you I did not realize that. Seem like I have to try some ways that make express point to right view folder

Comment: @Hung Which is the command what you used to start the server? You are using `Typescript` instead of Javascript code, then, maybe the destination folder  does not include the views folder.

Comment: @hoangdv I've tried to exclude "views" folder in tsconfig.json but it does not work. I start server with ts-node command

Comment: @Hung Add a "debugger" character to view path, and try again. `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views_debug'));`